How to fix errors when trying to make a server using the command parcel ./src/index.html
I'm very new to coding and I am trying to make a host server. (I am trying to learn ThreeJS). When I use the command I get an error message saying command parcel not found the only other thing that I found that might've helped was writing npx before the command that makes the server but it fails straight after. And give an error message saying a specific file was not found. Also I tryed doing the same command on bash and zsh.
Specifics:
I entered the code parcel ./src/index.htmlWhen I do this I get the - message bash: parcel: command not found. When I enter npx parcel ./src/index.html I recieve the message:
Server running at http://localhost:1234
 Build failed.
unknown: Entry /Users/(my full name)/Desktop/ThreeJsFolder/src/index.html does not exist.
Normally it should make a server like shown above but without it failing like it did.
